# How to prevent st from closing after executing a command provided with -e?

Tags: bash, terminal, i3

I want to make i3 show a terminal with the meaning of the word in the clipboard (using the trans command from translate-shell) when I press a keycombination, so I added this into `~/config/i3/config`:

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+t            exec $term  -e trans $(xclip -o)
```

The only problem is that the terminal closes immediately so I can't read the output.

I have `$term` set to `st`.

How can I prevent the terminal from closing immediately?

Comment: `xterm` provides option `-hold`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of executing `trans`, execute a child shell that runs `trans` and then waits until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
... $term -e sh -c 'trans "$(xclip -o)"; read junk'
```

Comment: I had to replace the ; with && cuz it did not work that way.

Comment: It will not work for calling tmux, for example. It just will close after you hit any key.

Comment: @banderlog013 If you just want to start an interactive `tmux` session in an `xterm` terminal, for example, just call `xterm -e tmux`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, but I want to do it with `st` terminal

Comment: @banderlog013 `st -e tmux`, it follows exactly the same pattern. See also the `st` manual on your system.

Comment: Yes, it worked before. Now I am switched to Ubuntu 20.04 and st just blinks and closes with any -e command. I've just checked -- 0.8.2 behaves the same. So it is not st problem, I think

Comment: @banderlog013 I can't reproduce what you're seeing. `st -e tmux` works as expected for me. You may want to ask a separate question about this.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am just forgot to do `tic -sx st.info`. So tmux argued like "tmux open terminal failed: missing or unsuitable terminal: st-256color", but I was able to see it only with `st -e bash -c 'tmux; read junk''`. Silly me. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @banderlog013 Ah, so it was a `TERM`-related issue. Note that you don't have to use `read junk` at the end of the command unless you need the window to hang around after `tmux` has terminated.